# Confidence interval for the square of binomial probability

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I have a binomial distribution where the estimate for *p* is 0.03 out of 1000 sample trials.

Using the normal approximation and Chi-square distribution for the square of normal distribution, how can I find a confidence interval for the square of *p*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\hat p \sim N\left(p, \frac {p(1-p)}n\right)$$
$$\frac {\sqrt n(\hat p -p)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \sim N\left(0,1\right)$$
$$\frac {n(\hat p -p)^2}{p(1-p)} \sim \chi^2(df=1)$$

Here $\sim$ means "asymptotically following"

Find the percentile of $\chi^2$ distribution. Let $X$ be its 2.5 percentile.
$$X<\frac {n(\hat p -p)^2}{p(1-p)} $$
$$-(X+n)p^2 + (X+2n\hat p)p -n\hat p^2 <0 $$
You can get the solution following the quadratic formula. Similarly, you can get other one using 97.5% percentile.

Answer (score 1):

There are better methods for your case: First, there are exact methods for a confidence interval for a binomial $p$, see [the many relevant posts here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+p+exact+confidence+interval+answers%3A1).

Use one such method and get a confidence interval $(l, u)$ for $p$. Then $(l^2, u^2)$ is a confidence interval for $p^2$.